# Prove the inequality using AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Given that $a,b,u,v \geq 0$ and $$a^5+b^5 \leq 1$$ $$u^5+v^5 \leq 1$$ Prove that $$a^2u^3+b^2v^3 \leq 1$$ This looks like Holder's inequality, but I found this problem in a book just after the AM-GM section. So, I wondered whether it could be solved using AM-GM (I wasn't able to do it, I don't know why- I am unable to get the square and the cubic term). Thanks.

Comment: Just because you mentioned Holder, giving that way too:
$$1\ge (a^5+b^5)^2(u^5+v^5)^3\ge(a^2u^3+b^2v^3)^5$$

Comment: Another way would be to use Muirheads inequality (hated by olympiad graders) and once you have figured that out use weighted AM GM to get the same solution which is much preferred. This is what @user26486 did essentially

Answer (score 18):

Hint: by AM-GM:

$$5a^2u^3\le a^5+a^5+u^5+u^5+u^5$$

$$5b^2v^3\le b^5+b^5+v^5+v^5+v^5$$

Add these up:

$$5a^2u^3+5b^2v^3\le 2(a^5+b^5)+3(u^5+v^5)$$

Now use the conditions given.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long did it take to solve that? The telltale a^2 u^3 along with the AM-GM hint suggests we use AM-GM on {a^5,a^5,u^5,u^5,u^5}

Comment: @smci We prove $A\le C$ by proving $A\le B$ with $B\le C$ being a known/simple inequality. In this case,

$$A=a^2u^3+b^2v^3\le \frac{a^5+a^5+u^5+u^5+u^5}{5}+\frac{b^5+b^5+v^5+v^5+v^5}{5}=B$$

with $B\le C=1$ given in the conditions. It's a very natural approach.

Comment: Yeah I understood, I said "use AM-GM on {a^5,a^5,u^5,u^5,u^5}". I merely asked how long it took to spot.

Comment: Also see Muirhead's inequality.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the most straightforward approach is given by [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality) with $p=\frac{5}{3},q=\frac{5}{2}$:

$$ a^2 u^3 \leq \frac{2}{5}a^5 + \frac{3}{5}u^5, \qquad b^2 v^3 \leq \frac{2}{5}b^5+\frac{3}{5}v^5$$
so by adding the two inequalities the claim $a^2 u^3 + b^2 v^3 \leq 1$ readily follows.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without even leaving a comment. I know the OP is supposed to use the AM-GM inequality, I just wanted to show that the Young's inequality is as much as effective.

Comment: The best answer ... +1